# How does std::string length() function work?

Tags: c++, string, loops

I can't understand why this loop prints "INFINITE". If the string length is 1, how can `length()-2` result in a big integer?

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length()-2;i++)
{
    cout<<"INFINITE"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint: a length can't be negative. As such, it doesn't need to be signed. Look up the type of `size_t`

Comment: Please poste a [MCVE]

Comment: Probably you have warning message but ignored it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string.length()` returns a `size_t`. This is an unsigned integer type. You are experiencing integer overflow. In pseudocode:

```
0 - 1 = int.maxvalue
```

In your case specifically it is:

```
(size_t)1 - 2 = SIZE_MAX
```

where `SIZE_MAX` usually equals 2^32 - 1

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::length()` returns a `std::string::size_type`.

`std::string::size_type` is specified to be the same type as `allocator_traits<>::size_type` (of the string's allocator).

This is specified to be an unsigned type.

Hence, the number will wrap (defined behaviour) and become huge. Precisely how huge will depend on the architecture.

You can test it on your architecture with this little program:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    using size_type = std::string::size_type;

    std::cout << "unsigned : " << std::boolalpha << std::is_unsigned<size_type>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size     : " << std::numeric_limits<size_type>::digits << " bits" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "npos     : " << std::hex << std::string::npos << std::endl;
}
```

in the case of apple x64:

```
unsigned : true
size     : 64 bits
npos     : ffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Do you have any source for `size_t` beeing allowed to be a signed integer?